# How to install r package on server

Tags: r, linux, package, shinydashboard, shiny-server

i am trying to install r package in ubuntu to deploy the app in shiny-server with required version i have tried the below code but it was throwing an error

```
Error: unexpected '/' in "install.packages(http:/"
Execution halted
```

Code:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shinydashboard/shinydashboard_0.6.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL)\""
```

Is there any other way to install this packages in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo su - \
-c "R -e \"install.packages('http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shinydashboard/shinydashboard_0.6.1.tar.gz',
repos=NULL, type ='source')\""
```

Comment: with this how to install required package version because i need to download this version shinydashboard_0.6.1.tar.gz"